# $b=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a^{i}$ sum of exponentional weights

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What is the relation between $a$ and $b$ if a is between 0 and 1?

$b=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a^{i}$

```
 b=0;
 for i=1:10000000
     b=b+0.9^i;
 end
 >>b=9
```

Comment: Keyword: [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula). Here $b = a\cdot\frac{1}{1-a}$.

Comment: This is a G.P series. Use sum for G.P series.

Comment: @AnirbanChatterjee a "geometric progression series"?

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks. Why don't you post it as an answer? I would gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: @PalimPalim In that case, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), i.e. a series of the form 
$$
\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \alpha r^n = \alpha^{n_0}\frac{1}{1-r}
$$
provided $\lvert r\rvert < 1$. Here, this leads to
$$
b=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n = a\cdot \frac{1}{1-a}.
$$
Note that for $a=0.9$, you do indeed get $\frac{0.9}{1-0.9} = 9$.